# Grant per user access to S3 bucket key using Multer-S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, multer-s3

I am uploading images to my S3 bucket via `multer-s3`.  Everything is working fine, the images gets dropped in my bucket.

```
var cloudStorage = multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'mybucket',
    acl: 'bucket-owner-full-control',
    serverSideEncryption: 'AES256',
    key: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.originalname)
    }
});

var upload  = multer({ 
            storage: cloudStorage,
            limits: {
                fileSize: 10000000,
                files: 6
            }).any()
```

The problem I am facing is that when a user uploads an image, and I go to the location of that image, I get an 'access denied' XML file.
How do I grant access to the files that the user that uploaded, but deny access for everyone else?

Comment: How you are trying to access the file?

Comment: @AlexBlex at the moment I just get the result back from my middleware and assign the file.location (URL) to an img src.

Comment: And how S3 should recognise that the http request came from the bucket owner? You need to retrieve a signed url from S3, or confirm user's identity.